# Physical Location of Android Emulator Database

Tags: android

Is it possible to access a SQLite database on an Android Emulator when the SDK & Eclipse are closed?  (e.g. directly, via filesystem)

I don't mind pulling it through Eclipse, but the Emulator has to be open, and for some reason, likes to shutdown when trying to pull the database file. It would just be easier if I could access it directly without the emulator, and without eclipse...

Surely it's persisted as a SQLite database somewhere in the file system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `adb` tool which comes with the SDK:

```
adb shell
cd /data/data/the.package/databases
sqlite3 name_of_database.db
```

If you want to access it without the emulator, you will have to pull it first:

```
adb pull /data/data/the.package/databases/name_of_database.db
```

Then close the emulator and use the sqlite3 command on your computer to access the database (or whatever app you want that allows you to open an sqlite database). Of course, if you do changes and want them to appear in the emulator again, you will have to push the modified database:

```
adb push name_of_database.db /data/data/the.package/databases/name_of_database.db
```

Comment: Cristian - Is there a better way to get there than navigating to the SDK through Windows command prompt?

Comment: Even better add a start menu shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to access a SQLite database on an Android Emulator when the SDK & Eclipse are closed? (e.g. directly, via filesystem)

If you mean "when the emulator is closed", then no.

> I don't mind pulling it through Eclipse, but the Emulator has to be open, and for some reason, likes to shutdown when trying to pull the database file.

FWIW, I have never had that happen to me.

> Surely it's persisted as a SQLite database somewhere in the file system?

In Android's file system in the emulator, yes. It is not a file in the file system of your development machine.

Comment: `Is it possible to access a SQLite database on an Android Emulator when the SDK & Eclipse are closed?` Are you sure you can't read from the filesystem image directly? I know not easily, but it's possible, no?

Comment: @Falmarri: If you can find a utility to let you yank files out of `userdata.img` safely, knock yourself out.